# Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore (PROD Build)

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error on during production build:

```
13% building modules 30/30 modules 0 activeWarning: Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore in **.../node_modules/angu
larfire2/firestore/index.d.ts: ([object Object], ?)**\. This will become an error in Angular v5.x
```

- Angular: 4.2.4
- Firebase: 4.5.0
- AngularFire: 5.0.0-rc.2
- @angular/cli: 1.4.4

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755589/2002079

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue on github.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1206

As said by davideast "We're working on this and should have something in before the 5.0 release."

Best we can do is wait or find a workaround which doesn't use fireangular.

Comment: I have a workaround for this. NOT to use angularfilre. Only use firebase from node package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase and use as per the instruction in the document.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing as well. It sucks but it is what it is. @RahulKapuriya